# If $A$ is a nilpotent matrix of order n, using the fact that $nullity(A^m)<nullity(A^{m+1})$ if $A^m \ne 0$, show that $A^n = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I feel that this statement should be proven by contradiction.

I started as follows

Suppose there exists $k \ne n$, such that $A^k = 0$,

$nullity(A^k) = nullity(A^n)$

I tried to break it down into two subcases, $k < n$ and $k > n$, but I do not know how to proceed from here.

Am I on the right track, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A^{n-1}=0$, you are done (why?). Assume $A^{n-1}\neq 0$, then also $A^m\neq 0$ for all $m\le n-1$. Hence,
$$
0 < nul(A) < nul(A^2) < \ldots < nul(A^n).
$$
What can you say now about $nul(A^n)$ and what does that mean for $A^n$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Suppose $A\ne0$.
Then $\text{nullity}(A^0)<\text{nullity}(A^1)$ implies $\text{nullity}(A^1)\ge1$.

By induction $\text{nullity}(A^i)\ge i,\,i=1,\cdots,m$, where $m$ is the smallest integer such that $A^m=0$.

Hope this helps.